# Visual Studio Code false errors at random

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have had issues with Visual Studio code creating errors and then not removing them, even when I comment out the code. Or , not creating errors when there should be errors. This happens on both my desktop and laptop, it will work for a while, giving me correct errors and then out of nowhere go berserk. What should I do to fix this?

Some examples:

[image: Some examples]

[image: Some examples]

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be caused by cached files. To clear the cache:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. type command **Clear Editor History**
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If this doesn't solve the problem, try this:

- Close the solution
- Remove the cache files inside the hidden `.vs` directory next to the
  solution file (move them elsewhere for the moment)
- Reopen the solution.

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the code, save the file and then run it again.

Or turn on the auto-save feature under `Files`

[Sample image of auto save turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GagyF.png)